# How do I set up the relationship between tables using firebase?

Tags: sql, firebase, nosql

I want to create a relational table on the google console screen using firebase. How can I make the relationship between the user table and the user's posts table on the google console screen

Answer (score 1):

Both databases offered by Firebase, Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore, are both NoSQL type databases.  [By definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL), this means that they are non-relational.  They do not have tables, and there are no joins.  You can't set up relationships between collections or nodes.

With Cloud Firestore, you can use a DocumentReference type field to have one document point to another document, but that doesn't help you with constructing a query that joins those two documents together.

If you want to use either of the databases that Firebase offers, please take some time to get acquainted with NoSQL data modeling techniques.  There are plenty of tutorials out there, as well as the product documentation for each product.

Answer (score 0):

NoSQL databases haven't data relationship with  tables. Also they also saves documents in a json format.

[nosql ecommerce data model maybe help for you](https://resources.fabric.inc/blog/nosql-ecommerce-data-model)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a logical relations between you documents.
take an example:

//customer
{
"id":23,
"name":"Mohammed"

}

//orders

[
{
"id":1,
"cust_id":23,
"products_sum":10

},
{
"id":2,
"cust_id":23,
"products_sum":20

}
]

this is one-to-many relationship between customer and orders.

*cust_id*  field will link these two documents